# RabbitMQ EventingBasicConsumer stops receiving messages

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using RabbitClient as Queue reader singleton in my .NET Core application (publishing to queue goes through other application). And I'm facing the problem when after some time my application stops reading from queue. I see queue full of messages, I push more and more but reader app is not reading until I restart It. Here is the code of RabbitClient:

```
private readonly IConnection _connection;

public RabbitClient(IMessagingConfiguration configuration)
{
    IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory { Uri = _configuration.ConnectionString };
    _connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
}

public void OnMessageAsync<T>(Func<T, Task> callback) where T : class
{
    T result;
    var queueName = _configuration.QueueName;
    var channel = _connection.CreateModel();
    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

    consumer.Received += (model, args) =>
    {
        var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args.Body);
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        callback(result).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        channel.BasicAck(args.DeliveryTag, false);
    };

    channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, noAck: false, consumer: consumer);
}
```

How can I force reader to keep reading without such stops?

Comment: When you stop receiving messages, does your consumer stay connected to the RabbitMQ server? You can check this in RabbitMQ admin UI

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ and the .NET client are you using? Did you search [GitHub issues](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/pull/275) for this?